# Delegate private method in bytebuddy with @Super - possible?

Tags: java, reflection, byte-buddy

I'm trying to delegate a private method in bytebuddy - but how do I call the 'overriden' version? If I have

```
    TypePool typepool = TypePool.Default.ofClassPath();
    new ByteBuddy()
        .rebase(typepool.describe("Foo").resolve(), ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.ofClassPath())
        .method(named("getNum"))
        .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(typepool.describe("FooInterceptor").resolve()))
        .make()
        .load(typepool.describe("Foo").resolve().getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent());

    Foo foo1 = new Foo();
    System.out.println("Foo says " + foo1.getMessage());
```

and

```
public class Foo
{
    private int num = 0;

    public String getMessage()
    {
        return "Message is Foo " + getNum();
    }
    private int getNum()
    {
        return num++;
    }
}
```

and

```
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super;

public class FooInterceptor
{
    public static int getNum(@Super Foo foo)
    {
        // This won't work!
        return foo.getNum() + 100;
    }
}
```

As far as the compiler is concerned, even if `@Super Foo foo` is going to become something else at runtime, I'm not allowed to call a private method on Foo. I don't seem to be able to reflect/invoke `getNum()` either - whatever `@Super Foo` becomes, it doesn't seem to have a `getNum()` method (although it does have a `getMessage()` method).

Can someone perhaps point me in the right direction here?

Update:

@Rafael's answer is technically a very good solution to the question I asked; unfortunately I guess my example was bad. Mea culpa. What I was really hoping for was a solution that would let me manipulate the arguments to `getNum()` before passing them. But it turns out that for my application I might be able to get by without doing that, so if that changes then perhaps I'll post that exact example.

Update 2:

Question completely answered! Hurray!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `@SuperCall Callable`. This would allow you to do invoke the overridden method from the method itself. It does however not allow you to invoke any method from within a proxied class.

```
public class FooInterceptor
{
  public static int getNum(@SuperCall Callable<Integer> c) throws Exception
  {
    // This will work!
    return c.call() + 100;
  }
}
```

If you need to manipulate the arguments, this is possible by using the `Morph` annotation. It allows you to invoke a method whilst supplying explicit arguments:

```
public interface Morphing<T> {
  T invoke(Object[] args);
}

public class FooInterceptor
{
  public static int getNum(@Morph Morphing<Integer> m, @AllArguments Object[] args)
  {
    // This will work!
    return m.invoke(args) + 100;
  }
}
```

Note that you need to install the interface explicitly:

```
MethodDelegation.to(FooInterceptor.class)
   .appendParameterBinder(Morph.Binder.install(Morphing.class));
```

Comment: Yeah - I saw this, but I was hoping to manipulate the arguments before passing them to the method (just realized this is a bad example because `getNum()` takes no arguments!), and my understanding is that if I have a Callable, those are curried/locked up inside.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you can provide explicit arguments.

Comment: how do I appendParameterBinder in Android?